# Insert each result of an array into separate SQL rows?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that is returning a different amount of `user_id`'s each time it's run (based on the number of `subscribers`).

What I need to do is insert each of these `user_id` results into separate rows within a table along with a simple message of "new alert" in a separate column.

How could I possibly go about doing this? Would a for each loop work in this situation?

Comment: Yes a foreach loop would work in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO alert_table SELECT user_id, 'new alert' FROM ... WHERE ...
```

Use your own query, just prepend it with the `INSERT INTO alert_table` clause.

Comment: Remember that columns count and order should match or define columns in insert: `INSERT INTO alert_table(column1, column2) SELECT source_column1, source_column2 FROM ...`